# Ignore line breaks in fputcsv

Tags: php, mysql, csv, fputcsv

I am currently trying to export a number of products from a custom CMS MYSQL database into a Magento compatible database.

The products include product descriptions which is stored as HTML that was serialised in a "ob_data" array with some other info when they were added through CMS system. Here is an example of one:

```
    Array
(
    [id] => 1085
    [type] => 9
    [url_key] => royal-worcester-mikado-milk-jug
    [name] => Royal Worcester Mikado 1/2 Pint Milk Jug
    [pattern] => Mikado
    [manufacturer] => Royal Worcester
    [stock] => 0
    [content] => &amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Bone china&amp;lt;br /&amp;gt;Holds approx1/2 pint.&amp;lt;br /&amp;gt;Excellent condition.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
    [weight] => 0.75
    [price] => 20.00
    [image] => /media/dContent/eCommerce/old/165.jpg
)
```

Using `unserialze` I can extract this and some other info into an array which can be written to the CSV. However when I write this information to a CSV file with `fputcsv` I get the following:

```
1085,9,royal-worcester-mikado-milk-jug,"Royal Worcester Mikado 1/2 Pint Milk Jug",Mikado,"Royal Worcester",0,"&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Bone china&amp;lt;br /&amp;gt;
Holds approx 1/2 pint.&amp;lt;br /&amp;gt;
Excellent condition.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;",0.75,20.00,/media/dContent/eCommerce/old/165.jpg
```

Essentially the `<br/>` tags that are in the description are also adding new lines in my CSV breaking its format and making it impossible to import.

Is there anyway that I can stop this happening and format the content so that it can comfortably written into the CSV?

Comment: `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` of php